# In PHP : What is the .htaccess file and what it will do?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Can any one give simple and brief answer for .htaccess file. Describe this in simple and understandable world.

Comment: .htaccess is a feature of the Apache web server, not PHP, and is well documented on the Apache site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because copy/pasting Apache's docs isn't productive. Please go read them. If you have _specific_ questions regarding that file format, please ask them on an appropriate site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software. When a .htaccess file is placed in a directory which is in turn 'loaded via the Apache Web Server', then the .htaccess file is detected and executed by the Apache Web Server software. These .htaccess files can be used to alter the configuration of the Apache Web Server software to enable/disable additional functionality and features that the Apache Web Server software has to offer. These facilities include basic redirect functionality, for instance if a 404 file not found error occurs, or for more advanced functions such as content password protection or image hot link prevention.

Here is an example of what you might include in a .htaccess file.

```
AuthName "Member's Area Name"
AuthUserFile /path/to/password/file/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages/401.html
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```